# How does Ignite for spark handle duplicate removal?

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I'm using Ignite as external data source of Spark, I need some hints to understand how Ignite for Spark handling duplicate removal of data loading from cache and files, it would be better to show me which class file is for that purpose, thanks.

Comment: Could you please give more details? What duplicates are you mentioning?

Comment: @VladimirPligin Thanks for reply, I mean when executing Spark SQL query, how does Spark guarantee uniqueness of result exist both in Ignite and HDFS, for example Person(1, 'Henrik') has been loaded into Ignite, so it exists both in Ignite and HDFS, when executing query spark.sql("select id, name from Person where id=1"), only 1 entry return but not 2.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to make updates between HDFS and Ignite synchronize. This needs to be done in some special ways:

1)You can try to implement Ignite Third Party cache store that will use some HDFS database (HIVE, HBASE):

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/custom-cache-store

After that you can set special policies that will explain how updates will be managed between HDFS:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#read-through-and-write-through

If write-through is set, each update from Ignite will be applied to the HDFS database. Read-Through will help to read data from the HDFS database if there is no value in Ignite.

Please note that exists ready-to-go solution for HDFS from GridGain vendor:

https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/integrations/datalake-accelerator/load-sync-hive

2)Another way can be implementing some transaction manager that will handle updates between Ignite and HDFS database. Something like this:

https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/jta/src/test/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/processors/cache/jta

However, Spark itself, as well as the ignite-spark integration, cannot sync two different databases out of the box. You must do this yourself before using Spark.

BR,
Andrei